# Why Flux iterable does not work in Spring Boot Controller for data from mongodb?

Tags: spring, mongodb, project-reactor

I have spring reactive webapp using reactive mongo driver for mongodb in a typical such app.

Below is the code in controller:

```
Flux<Foo> foos = fooService.findAllFoos();

Flux<Integer> squared = Flux.range(1, 10).map(x -> x * x);

Iterable<Integer> iter = squared.toIterable();
for (Integer i : iter) {
    log.info("square int is: " + i);
} 

Iterable<Foo> iter2 = foos.toIterable();
for (Foo foo : iter2) {
    log.info("ID is: " + foo.getId());
} 

int tm = 3;
```

iter works and prints values but iter2 does not print anything even though foos is not empty. Why ?

foos comes from:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;

public interface FooRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Foo, String> {    

    Flux<Foo> findAll();
}
```

Also it hangs, browser keeps waiting for request and last line of code (int tm =3 ) does not execute. Why?

Comment: Problem aside: If you want an `Iterable` then why start with a `Flux`?

Answer (score 0):

your stream is not sequential so try with below

```
    Flux<Foo> foos = fooService.findAll();
    return foos.flatMap(foo-> {
       //do something with foo
        return foo;

    }).switchIfEmpty(Flux.defer(() -> {
       //handle empty case.
        Iterable<Integer> iter = squared.toIterable();
        for (Integer i : iter) {
            log.info("square int is: " + i);
        }
        return 3;
    }));
```

**UPDATE**

To answer your question:

toIterable() is blocking stream so it will not executing next statements.so use flatmap on Mono or Flux.

Comment: Thank u but does not answer my questions. Also iter has nothing to do with foos or iter2, I just showed iter code to clarify

Comment: I have updated my answer why it is not executing your next statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is valid. There is only 1 explanation here:

iterator.next() is a blocking call. And since your code flow is blocked it means that the iterator is not yet ready. This could happen if fooService.findAllFoos() is returning a huge list and is taking time.

Can you tell how many records will be returned by fooService.findAllFoos()?

Or try deleting some records and let's say leave only a handful, say 2 0r 3 records and then see. I believe it should work then.

Iterator will not be ready unless there is a **complete** signal from the Flux.
Please check and let me know.